# Pythonでの固有値問題について

Tags: python

以下の data(5,10の行列) を直行変換して、対角行列を求めたと考えています。
しかし、うまく対角行列が得られなくて困っています。

どこか間違っているところはあるでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

**プログラム**

```py
#dataの固有値について考える
#相関行列R
R = np.corrcoef(data)
#固有値、固有ベクトル
w, C = LA.eig(R)

#dataを直行変換したdata_zを求める
data_z = np.array([])
for i in range(10):
    z = np.dot(C, np.transpose(data[:, i]))
    data_z = np.append(data_z, z)
data_z = data_z.reshape(10, 5)

#対角行列rを求めたい
#しかし、ｒが対角行列にならない
r = np.dot(z_, np.transpose(z_))
```

**対象データ**

```
#data
array([[-1.43536081,  0.31672281, -0.08760418, -0.7614825 , -0.02021635,
         1.46231594,  1.66447944,  0.58627413, -1.36797298, -0.35715551],
       [-1.40345563, -0.35240956,  1.50237761, -0.4142358 , -1.77441306,
         1.06959394,  0.08037411,  1.0077677 , -0.10510461,  0.38950531],
       [-1.53225887,  0.21367519,  0.18593929, -0.76816204, -0.34940435,
         1.53962792,  1.51869003,  0.71822383, -1.26428114, -0.26204986],
       [-1.37462585,  0.27390587, -0.1306024 , -0.77267902, -0.0641876 ,
         1.49846638,  1.72660423,  0.55160401, -1.31623701, -0.39224862],
       [-1.39815422, -0.36117539,  1.51740696, -0.42272585, -1.75938822,
         1.07351947,  0.07160888,  1.01038282, -0.11428387,  0.38280943]])
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/226950

Comment: 「直行変換」は直交変換(orthogonal transformation)の事でしょうか？ また、式 `r = np.dot(z_, np.transpose(z_))` 内の `z_` は `data_z` でしょうか？

Comment: @itaita さん、複数のご質問で別のサイトへ同じ質問を投稿なさっているようにお見受けします。このような行為はマルチポストやクロスポストと呼ばれ、スタック・オーバーフローでは気を付けて頂きたい点がございます。こちらをご一読くださると幸いです: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)。また Teratail においても[このように](https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice)書かれています。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします<(\_ \_)>

Answer (score 2):

複数の問題があります。

- `data` は非正方行列です。固有値は正方行列でないと存在しないものであり、非正方行列に対しては特異値など他の概念を使うことになります。特に `numpy.linalg.eig` は正方行列に対して使われることが想定されています。
- コードを見ると `data` の相関行列 `R` の固有ベクトルが `data` の固有ベクトルであるかのように扱われています。
- そもそも固有値がすべて求まっているのであればそれらを対角要素に並べれば対角化の結果になります。